# Why import my own cad file is more slow than import PR2 cad model?

Tags: ros, gazebo, cad

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to covert my own cad file to stl file.
And I use the command to import

```
  rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file foot.urdf -urdf -model top -z 0.5
```

I have waited several minutes but do not see any progress or message.

Why it be so slow? And how do I speed up?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10802/why-import-my-own-cad-file-is-more-slow-than-import-pr2-cad-model?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-08-05**:
Please upload your URDF and STL files somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried to reduce the resolution of my stl file.
I found 3 ways to do it,and I only try the third.

1.Use SOLIDCast to reduce the triangle number.

http://www.cast-cae.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=385

2.Use 3ds Max to reduce the vertex.

http://www.ddove.com/3dmax/sl/tut_using_the_vertex_weld_modifier.html

3.Use Inventor to export stl file with options.

It can be choice : high,medium,low,custom

What I found is if I try to import the same motor stl with different resolution successfully,

```
 load motor_lowest.stl（296k，about 0 sec）
 load motor_low.stl（512k，about 0 sec）
 load motor_medium.stl（1028k，about 3 sec）
 load motor_high.stl（2820k，about 10 sec）
 load motor_highest.stl（51M, very very long）
```

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2011-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1